# WPF Label or Textblock Display Member by selected ID

Tags: wpf, data-binding

How to accomplish this easy?

**First of all, I know I can - but I don't want to add additional property string to my viewmodel.**

If I make this:

```
<ComboBox
IsEnabled="False"
IsReadOnly="True"
ItemsSource="{Binding SomeListOfIdValuePairs}"
DisplayMemberPath="Value"
SelectedValuePath="Id"
SelectedValue="{Binding SomeViewModel.DesiredId, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

**It works fine! However** the Arrow of the combobox is disturbing me here and there is no easy way `HideArrow="True"` to hide it but to write a long whole combobox template.

So, how could I do something this instead?

```
<TextBlock
ItemsSource="{Binding SomeListOfIdValuePairs}"
DisplayMemberPath="Value"
SelectedValuePath="Id"
SelectedValue="{Binding SomeViewModel.DesiredId, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Use a MultiBinding for the Text property, with an appropriate multi-value converter.

Comment: @Clemens I don't want additional value converters. Any other solutions? This should be really simple.

Comment: @Clemens is there a usable value converter for this and if so do you have any example?

Comment: No, you have to write your own.

Comment: Setting ComboBox.IsEditable to true will turn it into a pseudo TextBox.

Comment: @BionicCode cool, however still shows the dropdown arrow :/

Answer (score -2):

I guess you need the `ComboBox` features and therefore a simple `TextBlock` is not a solution.

You have to override the `ComboBox` template as the arrow is part of the `ToggleButton`.

You can of course find the arrow in the visual tree and remove it by collapsing it:

```xml
<ComboBox Loaded="OnComboBoxLoaded" />
```

```cs
private void OnComboBoxLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Path arrow = FindVisualChild<Path>(sender as DependencyObject);
  arrow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

You can find a `FindVisualChild` implementation at [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#example). You probably already have your own version.